# Notification error

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there any way to launch custom errors in the admin site like that?:

[image]

Currently I throw the error with

```
raise forms.ValidationError('error')
```

but shows the debug error screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967110/django-validation-error-in-admin should give you an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you putting the `raise forms.ValidationError('error')`?

In your form clean() method is a good place to raise custom errors. You can even do `def clean_fieldname()` to preform specific validation for one field. From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

```
from django import forms

    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        # Everything as before.
        ...

        def clean_recipients(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
            if "fred@example.com" not in data:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")

            # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
            # not.
            return data
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369548/django-admin-custom-error-message) also could help